# How do I get the Payer Address entered during a Paypal Guest Checkout (Adaptive API)

Tags: paypal

I'm using the embedded Adaptive Paypal API for two receivers, with the option to select Guest Checkout. I have the payKey that I generated to create the Pay request. But I just can't figure out how to get the address the buyer enters in during checkout. I've tried the 'GetPaymentDetails' command and I get a valid reply with basic transaction information, but no address information. I was going to also try the 'GetExpressCheckoutDetails' command, but it requires a token and all I have is a payKey. Very frustrating. Hope someone knows how to do this.